# zf2 form filter treat 0 as integer and empty string as null

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-filter

This question may be obvious to some :)

I've got an input which needs to handle numeric values and then filter/validate when empty as null. 
Every method I've tried has resulted in the value either being treat as 0 both when empty and having a value of 0 or as null when empty or having a value of 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Could you provide some examples of valid and invalid input values?

Comment: Basically, I have a stock level, where 1+ is actual stock, 0 is out of stock and NULL is always available.

I think my issue might be part of a larger issue. I can't seem to get any ZF2 filters to work.



$passwordNew = new InputFilter\Input( 'new_password' );$passwordNew->allowEmpty( true );
        $passwordNew->setRequired( false );
        $passwordNew->getFilterChain()->attachByName( 'StringTrim' );
        $passwordNew->getFilterChain()->attachByName( 'Null' );
        $inputFilter->add( $passwordNew ); That code doesn't seem to be applied as trailing spaces are still present.